# In set notation, how do I "read" the following: "f : Z -> R"

Tags: notation

In words, how would I express this notation?

"Given a random variable $f:Z\rightarrow \mathbb R$, its expected value is denoted by $\mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{D}}[f(z)]$"

This is from the first chapter of "Understanding Machine Learning" by Shwartz:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skD5a.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtG3i.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the notation means that $f$ is a function whose domain is $Z$ and whose range is (a subset of ) $R.$ In this context, I would guess $Z$ is the sample space and $R$ is the real numbers based on the [mathematical definition of a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition).

Comment: Thank you.  And do you know how to read the second part? $\mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{D}}[f(z)]$

Comment: Honestly this is not the usual mathematical notation and I don't have the book in front of me to contextualize it. If I had to guess, I'd say that $z\sim \mathcal D$ is expressing that $z$ (an element from the sample space) is drawn from some distribution (in the standard mathematical framework, $\mathcal D$ would correspond to the probability measure on the sample space). I would guess that you would expand this to something like $$ \mathbb E_{z\sim \mathcal D}[f(z)] = \int f(z)p_{\mathcal D}(z)\, dz$$ where $p_{\mathcal D}(z)$ is the probability distribution on the sample space.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added image links if that helps. https://i.stack.imgur.com/skD5a.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtG3i.png

Comment: Yeah, I think that validates what I said above. $E_{z\sim \mathcal D}(f(z))$ is just the expectation value of the RV $f$ and they say they often sensibly abbreviate the notation to $E(f).$ I think they're being precise here to get you used to their formalism.